# Windowing Functions with cpp in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, codeblocks

I have been learning OpenGL with cpp using www.cplusplus.com . I have been using Code Blocks and the program goes like this

```
/*  Trim fat from windows*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows")
/*  Pre-processor directives*/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
/*  Windows Procedure Event Handler*/
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    /*  Device Context*/
    HDC hDC;
    /*  Text for display*/
    char string[] = "Hello, World!";
    /*  Switch message, condition that is met will execute*/
    switch(message)
    {
        /*  Window is being created*/
        case WM_CREATE:
            return 0;
            break;
        /*  Window is closing*/
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
            break;
        /*  Window needs update*/
        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&paintStruct);
            /*  Set txt color to blue*/
            SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));
            /*  Display text in middle of window*/
            TextOut(hDC,150,150,string,sizeof(string)-1);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam));
}
/*  Main function*/
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  windowClass;        //window class
    HWND        hwnd;               //window handle
    MSG         msg;                //message
    bool        done;               //flag saying when app is complete
    /*  Fill out the window class structure*/
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "MyClass";
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    /*  Register window class*/
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    /*  Class registerd, so now create window*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,     //extended style
        "MyClass",          //class name
        "A Real Win App",       //app name
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |       //window style
        WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_SYSMENU,
        100,100,            //x/y coords
        400,400,            //width,height
        NULL,               //handle to parent
        NULL,               //handle to menu
        hInstance,          //application instance
        NULL);              //no extra parameter's
    /*  Check if window creation failed*/
    if (!hwnd)
        return 0;
    done = false; //initialize loop condition variable
    /*  main message loop*/
    while(!done)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //check for a quit message
        {
            done = true; //if found, quit app
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Translate and dispatch to event queue*/
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

I have compiled this and finally getting the linker errors that SetTextColor, TextOut and GetStockObject are "undefined reference to". I have been including all the required files but finally again and again landing into the same trouble.

I have been including the "stdafx.h" and  but without any success. I am landing into the same trouble again. Any way of getting round this error?

Comment: have you tried including Wingdi.h, the header where these functions are declared?

Comment: Yup. But it looks that it has no effect.

Comment: As long as `stdafx.h` includes `windows.h` you should be fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make a comment here for some reason, so I'll put it in an answer:

Du you really mean that this is a compiler error ("not defined")? Because if it is a linker error ("undefined reference to..."), it means that you have not included the corresponding library (gdi32 I believe).

Comment: It is a linker error. But how do i ink to that exact corresponding library?

Comment: Go to Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Link Liraries, and add "gdi32.dll" to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Does Code Blocks support precompiled headers? If it does, everything that comes before stdafx.h is ignored by the compiler. Nothing but comments should be above it in the cpp file.

The purpose of stdafx.h is to efficiently bring in declarations that will not change between compilations. So you should move all of those #define, #pragma and #include statements into the stdafx.h file.